# How to create and append PushPins to map using ArcGis API?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Hi all i want to create a PushPin inside a map using ArcGis API After long time of researching the only viable option seems to add a graphic layer on top of the map layer and drawing symbols on it.

But after i tried the following codes and run on the WP7 emulator. No PushPin seemed to be generated when i click on the map. ANy help is greatly appreciated. Really thx alot in advance.

*Note map1 in the code sample refers to the ArcGis Map object

Code Sample:

```
private void map1_MapGesture(object sender, Map.MapGestureEventArgs e)
{
    SimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol()
    {
        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0, 0)),
        BorderThickness = 2,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 12, 12, 255))
    };

    GraphicsLayer layer = map1.Layers["PushpinLayer"] as GraphicsLayer;
    Graphic g = new Graphic();
    g.Symbol = fillSymbol;
    g.Geometry = e.MapPoint;
    layer.Graphics.Add(g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used next code to draw pushpins on the map:

```
<Maps:Map>
    <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Pushpins} ItemTemplate={StaticResource CustomTemplate} />
</Maps:Map>
```

Where `Pushpins` is your collection of objects that have inside it a public property `GeoCoordinate Location` to place pushpin on the specific location.

That you can add new items on gesture event:

```
Pushpins.Add(new Pushpin(...));
```

Also, consider to use `ObservableCollection` as your pushpin collection type

Comment: Do ArcGis provide a Pushpin class?

Comment: I though you get from ArcGis some coordinates of objects and then you need to draw them. I'm right? If you need some geometry placed on the map, look to the `MapPolygon` class instead. In my implementation `Pushpin` is custom class with `Location` inside.

Comment: Oh no  sorry if it wasn't clear. Because i'm using ArcGis API to display the map. So i need to put pushpins inside the map and was wondering if i am doing the right way

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thx for all those who viewed my post :)
And especially if answered =P

Anyway i found out is that the problem is inside my xaml i put the graphics layer before the map layer hence the graphics won't be rendered.

Anyway this should be the correct way to order the elements =P

Really appreciate all your help :)

```
<esri:Map Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" WrapAround="True" Height="607" Width="468" MapGesture="map1_MapGesture">
            <esri:Map.Layers>
                <esri:LayerCollection>
                    <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer Url="http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/BASEMAP/MapServer" />
                    <esri:GraphicsLayer Visible="True" ID="PushpinLayer" />
                </esri:LayerCollection>
            </esri:Map.Layers>
        </esri:Map>
```